# How can I modify my tcblisting to show input code and the expected output side-by-side?

Tags: listings, minipage, verbatim, minted, tcblisting

I have a code listing and `tcblisting` defined as follows.

```
\lstdefinelanguage{MyScheme}{
  basewidth=0.5em,
  morekeywords=[1]{define, cond, lambda, else},
  alsodigit=!\$\%&*+-./:<=>?@^_~,
  sensitive=true,
  escapeinside={(*;}{;*)},
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bf\ttfamily\color[rgb]{0,.3,.7},
  commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
  stringstyle={\color[rgb]{0.75,0.49,0.07}},
  upquote=true,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  literate=*{`}{{`}}{1},
  showstringspaces=false,
}
```

```
\newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=chapter]{MySchemeListing}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    frame hidden, 
    breakable,
    borderline north = {0.5pt}{0pt}{black},
    borderline south = {0.5pt}{0pt}{black},
    opacityfill=0,
    listing only,
    top=-5pt,bottom=-5pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,
    listing options={
        basewidth=0.5em,
        commentstyle=\color{orange},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        morekeywords={NULL},
        language=MyScheme,
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
        breaklines=true,
        showstringspaces=false,
        escapeinside={(*;}{;*)},
        literate={~}{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textasciitilde}}1{'}{\textquotesingle}1{`}{\textasciigrave}1
    },
    title={\textcolor{black}{Listing \thetcbcounter\ifstrempty{#2}{}{---#2}\ifstrempty{#1}{}{~(\texttt{#1})}}},
    attach boxed title to top center={xshift=-3.55mm,yshift=-0.4mm},
    boxed title style={frame hidden,colback=black!0!white},
    minted language=scheme,
    minted options={autogobble},
}
```

I'd like to be able to show both the input code *and* output results side-by-side. Right now, I use a separate tcb environment that puts the output below the code (not shown because it's really not relevant). Ideally, I'd be able to just add something to the `MySchemeListing` so I don't need to go through and update all the listings. I've tried adding a verbatim minipage environment, but the issue is that the header I use for the scheme listings doesn't go over the output. Additionally, I'd like the output to start at the top of the listing like the code does (rather than being vertically shifted down).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[minted,skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, skins, breakable}

%%% Two listings from above...

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{MySchemeListing}[main.rkt]{Factorial}
(define fact
  (lambda (n)
    (cond
      [(zero? n) 1]
      [else (* n (fact (sub1 n)))])))
\end{MySchemeListing}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
>>> 5
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Here is the current output:
[image]

versus what I'm looking for (just edited in a photo editor), with perhaps a dashed line separating the input from output:
[image]

Note that the 5 that currently exists is just a placeholder for other stuff that could be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use a `tcolorbox` and cut my losses via a `lstlisting`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[minted,skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, skins, breakable}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyScheme}{
  basewidth=0.5em,
  morekeywords=[1]{define, cond, lambda, else},
  alsodigit=!\$\%&*+-./:<=>?@^_~,
  sensitive=true,
  escapeinside={(*;}{;*)},
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bf\ttfamily\color[rgb]{0,.3,.7},
  commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
  stringstyle={\color[rgb]{0.75,0.49,0.07}},
  upquote=true,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  literate=*{`}{{`}}{1},
  showstringspaces=false,
}

\newtcolorbox[list inside=mybox,auto counter,number within=section]{MyBox}[2][]{
colback=gray!5!white,
colframe=gray!75!black,
sidebyside,
sidebyside align=top,
boxsep=1pt,
left=5pt,
right=5pt,
top=2pt,
bottom=0pt,
lefthand width={0.60\textwidth},
title={Listing \thetcbcounter\;[\texttt{#1}]: #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyBox}[fact.scm]{Factorial Program}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=MyScheme]
;; ! : Number -> Number
;; Computes the factorial of a number.
(define !
 (lambda (n)
  (cond
   [(zero? n) 1]
   [else (* n (! (sub1 n)))])))
\end{lstlisting}
\tcblower
\begin{lstlisting}[language=MyScheme]
(*;\textbf{>{>}>};*) (! 5)
120
\end{lstlisting}
\end{MyBox}

\end{document}
```